# Cant update wpf datagrid through table adapter after creating new Fill method

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tableadapter

I have a problem with the table adapter update function used in WPF `DataGrid`.
The thing is that I could Fill my table adapter with my `DataSet` table name like this:

```
ApplicationTableAdapter.Fill(myAppDataSet.AccountingIncome);
```

and then listen for `RowChange` and update my table adapter like this:

```
Dataset.AccountingIncome.AccountingIncomeRowChanged += new     HomeApplication.TheHomeApplicationDBDataSet.AccountingIncomeRowChangeEventHandler(AccountIncomeRowModified);
```

and updating like this:

```
 ApplicationTableAdapter.Update(Dataset.AccountingIncome);
```

This works all well.

But I need to perform another fill for my `DataGrid` so I created new Select query and now I´m filling my datagrid with

```
ApplicationTableAdapter.FillByYearAndMonth(myAppDataSet.AccountingIncome);
```

after I change data in my `DataGrid`, I get the following error for my `Update` function:

```
Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.
```

What do I need to do so I can `Update again` after using the new Fill method ?

any ideas ?

Comment: How are you binding the data to the datagrid? Datatable, ObservalbeCollection?

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource accountingIncomeViewSource}}"